# using jquery ajax to open a different jsp

Tags: jquery

Heres my scenario: multiple jsp pages all with fields and after a user has filled in all fields on a single page they click a "next" button to go to the next page. I need to load in the next jsp into the window.

How using jquery ajax can I do this?

Here is my code.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(event){
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "Request.jsp"                
        });
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(event){
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "Request.jsp"
            success: function(data){ window.location="/Page.jsp"});
        });

});
```

Here you load "Request.jsp" data in to div with id "response"

If you want to load other jsp file you can use load() function.

Something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Back to Previous Page" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)">

<input type="button" value="Go to Next Page" onClick="javascript: history.go(+1)">
```

Comment: I don't have a div with id "response" I want to view just the new jsp

Comment: yes I do. But I don't want to just use href's because I will eventually need to cache the data on each page because the user will be able to go forward and backwards through the pages

Comment: Then you can use `window.location="Page.jsp"` ?!

Comment: I apologize if my questions seem trivial, but this is my first time working with jquery-ajax and this stuff isn't intuitively obvious for me

Comment: You are my hero!! Now my next question is will I run into an issue with caching later on...I currently have zero idea how to do that but will have to figure it out eventually

Comment: My primavista idea is you can use `javascript: history.go(-1)`