# Making jQuery tabs point to different urls

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I am using jQuery to display tabs and want each of the tabs to point to different jsps.

I did it this way.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Real updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">My Wall</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Friends</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <jsp:include page="realupdates.jsp" />

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <jsp:include page="wall.jsp" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <jsp:include page="friends.jsp" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This works. But if the included jsps themselves contain jQuery.. then tabbing system stops to work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your jQuery code? Also this thread might help. It seems to be kind of similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413040/using-jquery-ajax-to-open-a-different-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using '[forward](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro9.html)' instead of 'include'?  It's supposed to transfer control dynamically

```
<jsp:forward page="/realupdates.jsp" />
```

Comment: no this does not work. The page control directly transfers to the first jsp forward page and the tabbed page doesn't show at all.